# Adjust UIPopover when the iPad keypad splits

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have an iPad app in landscape orientation.
Which has multiple UIButtons on the screen from top to bottom which present a UIPopover with a TextView in it.

When the keyboard appears and covers the button, the popover moves over the keyboard, and comes back nicely when the keyboard is dismissed.

but when the keyboard is suddenly put into split mode and if the popover was for a button below the keyboard then the popover comes back and goes behind one of the halves of the keyboard.

How should such situation be handled gracefully ?

Answer (score 0):

Would creating a transparent view/button that you launch the Popover view from work? Then you could move the button to where ever you want.